# Two Update Queries in Stored Procedure: Not executing 2nd Update Query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure that will update two tables at the same time. When I tried executing, the 2nd query is not executing, the first update query only.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateEmployeeCategory]
@EMPLEVEL nvarchar(50),
@EMPCATEGORY nvarchar(50),
@SELECTEDCAT nvarchar(50)
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE tbl_13Month_Computation
SET EmpCategory = @EMPCATEGORY
WHERE EmpLevel = @EMPLEVEL
AND EmpCategory = @SELECTEDCAT

UPDATE tbl_Salary_Payout
SET EmpCategory = @EMPCATEGORY
WHERE Emplevel = @EMPCATEGORY
AND EmpCategory = @SELECTEDCAT
END
```

What will I add to my queries to execute the 2nd update? Thank you.

Comment: Double check your variable use in the second where clause; specifically `Emplevel = @EMPCATEGORY`. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: It is updating, I'm 100% certain your update statement, expectations or tests are incorrect.

Comment: @R.Richards OHH! Thank you. I forgot to check my parameters. It works now. Thank you again.